# What went wrong when I'm creating a new variable?

Tags: r

I'd like to create a new variable based on condition imposed on the original variable. Let's say

- the original variable, "var", is a vector consisted of a random sample from 1...20, and
- the new variable "newvar" is set to be missing when the original "var" is greater than 10, and equal to "var" when "var" is less than 10.

The codes below describe the procedure,

```
> mydata <- data.frame(var=sample(1:20))
> mydata$newvar <- rep(NA, nrow(mydata))
> mydata$newvar[mydata$var < 10] <- mydata$var
Warning message:
In mydata$newvar[mydata$var < 10] <- mydata$var :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

As the warning message indicates, the result is terrible. For example, in row 4 and 5, "newvar" is being assigned the values of "var" in row 2 and 3, respectively. Can you please tell me what went wrong?

```
> mydata
   var newvar
1    3      3
2   16     NA
3   13     NA
4    5     16
5    7     13
6   19     NA
7    4      5
8   17     NA
9    9      7
10  20     NA
11  14     NA
12   8     19
13  10     NA
14   6      4
15   1     17
16  11     NA
17  18     NA
18  15     NA
19   2      9
20  12     NA
```

I am relatively new to R and is still learning how to manipulate variables and data. To create the new variable, I understand that I can just loop through the indices that need to be changed as shown below

```
mydata$newvar <- rep(NA, nrow(mydata))  
loop_through_these <- which(mydata$var < 10)

for(i in loop_through_these){

  mydata$newvar[i] <- mydata$var[i]
}
> mydata
    var newvar
1    3      3
2   16     NA
3   13     NA
4    5      5
5    7      7
6   19     NA
7    4      4
8   17     NA
9    9      9
10  20     NA
11  14     NA
12   8      8
13  10     NA
14   6      6
15   1      1
16  11     NA
17  18     NA
18  15     NA
19   2      2
20  12     NA
```

This, although not the most efficient, gives me the correct result. Still I think there is a more efficient way than using a loop. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It worked perfectly-thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using either [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) or [`which`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html). With `ifelse` you don't need to create the column of `NA`s first:

```
mydata$newvar <- ifelse(mydata$var < 10, mydata$var, NA)
```

If you have already created the column of `NA`s, this will work:

```
mydata$newvar[which(mydata$var < 10)] <- mydata$var[which(mydata$var < 10)]
```

Comment: `which()` is not necessary.

Comment: Good point @RHertel. I used it because the OP did and thought the documentation might be helpful, but you're right that it works without this as Zheyuan Li's answer shows.